# Написание НН в причастиях и отглагольных прилагательных

Tags: нн

Стало интересно, почему в таких словах, как *сложноподчинённый*, *сложносочинённый*, пишется НН. Вроде как *сложно-* в данном случае является корнем, а не приставкой, да и вообще признаки указывают, что это отглагольные прилагательные, но при этом всё равно пишется НН.

Можете сказать, почему так?

Answer (score 3):

**Дополнение к предыдущему ответу**

В вопросе говорится о приставке, которая является одним из факторов написания Н/НН, и о том, что первая часть слов *сложноподчиненный* и *сложносочиненный* не является таковой. Вопрос, видимо, возник потому, что в настоящее время слова ***подчиненный*** и ***сочиненный*** рассматриваются как бесприставочные. По крайней мере на ресурсах, предлагающих морфемный разбор слов, указаны корни ***подчин-, сочин-***. Например, [здесь](http://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%A1/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

Получается, что в современном языке изначальные приставки ПОД- и СО- окончательно утратили свое значение в словах этого ряда, а написание осталось с НН. Чтобы узнать этимологию слова достаточно зайти в Викисловарь:

> Происходит от гл. *подчинять*, далее от существительного **чин**... ([источник](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9))
>
> Происходит от гл. *сочинять (сочинить)*, из **со- + чинить**, далее от **чин**... ([источник](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Comment: Александр, а так ли здесь важна приставка? Ведь для выбора НН в словах "подчиненный и сочиненный" достаточно совершенного вида глаголов, от которых они образованы.

Comment: Посмотрел еще раз правила. Там говорится о бесприставочных причастиях. В вопросе же - о прилагательных, т. е. указано на противоречие (что якобы у них должна быть Н). Думаю, что это изначальные причастия, перешедшие в категорию прилагательных.

Answer (score 1):

Сложные прилагательные ***сложноподчинённый, сложносочинённый*** образуются путем сращения первой основы и опорного прилагательного, поэтому сохраняется форма написания опорных слов  ***подчиненный и сочиненный***.

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62

4. В составе сложного слова написание отглагольного прилагательного также **не меняется:** **гладкокрашеный,** горячекатаный, холоднокатаный, цельнокатаный, цельнокроеный, домотканый, пестротканый, златотканый, златокованый, малоезженый, малохоженый, малоношеный, малосолёный, мелкодроблёный, свежегашёный, свежемороженый и др. (ср. с терминами, в которых вторая часть сложного слова образована от приставочного глагола: **гладкоокрашенный**, малонаезженный, свежезамороженный и др.).